# How do I "unfold" my text file?

Tags: python

I had a data table I converted to a text file with a tilde `~` at the end of each line.  This is how I ended each line, so it is not a delimiter.

I used Linux to fold the data into an 80 byte length wrapped text file and added a line feed at the end of each line.

Example (if I did this at 10 bytes per line):

#### Original file or table:

```
abcdefghigklmnop~
1234567890~
```

#### New file:

```
abcdefghig
klmnop~123
4567890~
```

Linux/Unix, Perl, or even Python responses would help and be appreciated.

I need the new file to look exactly like the original. Sometimes line lengths will be over 80 characters in length which is ok.

Comment: So the original delimiter was `~\n` then? So to reverse it sound like you only need to remove newlines and replace all `~` characters with `~\n` again.

Comment: *"This is how I ended each line, so it is not a delimiter."* I'm afraid a delimiter is *exactly* what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your original data was delimited by `~\n` (tildes at the end of a line), and the new format removed the newlines and inserted new ones every 80 bytes, then the reverse is to remove newlines and replacing `~` with `~\n` again:

```
with open(inputfile, 'r') as inp, open(outputfile, 'w') as outp:
    data = inp.read().replace('\n', '')
    outp.write(data.replace('~', '~\n'))
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Comment: The code worked!  When I checked it through a text editor it did not look like the formatting worked.  I tried again one more time with the original code since you sent me this message, and although it still did not look correct I applied it to my process with the assumption it would work, with success.  I appreciate your help, timely response, and interest in following back up to make sure I was all set.  This was a great learning experience for me.  Thank you!